# Regex to get vimeo video id in swift 2

Tags: ios, regex, swift

I have vimeo url

> https://vimeo.com/video/17314292

and I need only video id.
But don,t have any idea how to get using regex in swift 2.0.

or any other that will safe even if vimeo url contains something else.

Answer (score 1):

Given your URL definition, you can just use this

```
NSRegularExpression(pattern: "([0-9]+)", options: [.CaseInsensitive])
```

and get the first match using

```
firstMatchInString
```

Comment: url I am getting from server that may come in other form. Like it may contain some alphabets

Answer (score 1):

Fixing JackTurky's answer, changing Regex you should use this as follows

```
NSRegularExpression(pattern: "(?<=video/)([a-z0-9]*))", options: [.CaseInsensitive])
```

and get the first match using

```
firstMatchInString
```

If you need some other characters like -, you just add them after 9

Answer (score 0):

To get video id from Vimeo video link, use code for Swift4 :

```
if yourLink.lowercased().contains("vimeo.com") {
            videoId = yourLink.vimeoID ?? ""
 }
```

where, **.vimeoID** is defined in "String" extension:

```
extension String {

// Vimeo VideoID from Link(url)

var vimeoID: String? {
    let pattern = "([0-9]+)"

    let regex = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: .caseInsensitive)
    let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: count)

    guard let result = regex?.firstMatch(in: self, range: range) else {
        return nil
    }

    return (self as NSString).substring(with: result.range)
} }
```

Hope will help! :)